# Как записать русские буквы в массив?

Tags: c++, qt

char arr[] = {'а', 'б', 'в', 'г'} когда я пишу такой массив выдаёт ошибку  "ошибка: excess elements in char array initializer" что нужно сделать что бы исправить? Я писал не консольное приложение в Qt (если это нужно)

Comment: В какой кодировке вы хотите хранить кириллицу? Если UTF-8, то кириллица занимает по два байта, и нужно хранить каждую букву в `std::string` или в чем-то подобном.

Comment: Зачем тег Qt? Если используете Qt, тогда ненужно использовать `char`, в Qt достаточно средств для работы с Unicode.

Comment: Еще убедитесь что файл исходника у вас `utf-8`, если кириллица будет в самом коде

Comment: Что за компилятор, IDE, ОС? в VS это компилируется без проблем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш исходный код имеет какую-то кодировку, символы кириллицы пишутся в код в этой кодировке. Запись char arr[] = {'а', 'б', 'в', 'г'} подразумевает, что вы набираете код в однобайтной кодировке, и инициализируете байтовый массив кодами букв кириллицы именно в этой кодировке, в то время когда современные IDE используют по умолчанию юникод (например utf-8), отсюда и ошибка компиляции. Если вам действительно необходим массив символов в юникоде, то на Qt можете инициализировать его так:`QChar arr[] = {u'а', u'б', u'в', u'г'}`

Answer (score 1):

Тип char не поддерживаёт юникод. Поэтому используй тип wchar_t.